# How to add calculated columns to the source DataFrame

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

In SparkR (Databricks) I am able to calculate, let's say, mean value for column B based on grouped values from columns A and C as in here:

```
library(SparkR)

df <- createDataFrame (
list(list(1L, 1, "1", 0.1), list(1L, 2, "1", 0.2), list(3L, 3, "3", 0.3)),
  c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

result <- gapplyCollect(
  df,
  c("a", "c"),
  function(key, x) {
    y <- data.frame(key, mean(x$b), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    colnames(y) <- c( "key_a", "key_c", "mean_b")
    y
  })
```

Here the source data frame - **df** - is used to produce a new one - **result** - with the results - **mean_b** for **key_a** and **key_c**.
This is working fine, but how to do the same operation WITHOUT creating new data frame? So that **mean_b** is added as a new column to **df**?

Comment: have you tried `df <- gapplyCollect(` instead of `result <- gapplyCollect(` ?

Comment: @AlexOtt - yes, it is getting overwritten with what is in the colnames section: colnames(y) <- c( "key_a", "key_c", "mean_b") So no previous data is not preserved..

Answer (score 0):

A **left join** can add the `result$mean_b` as a new column to the original `df` using the aggregation keys.

Observe the following code:

```
library(SparkR)

df <- createDataFrame (
list(list(1L, 1, "x", 0.1), list(1L, 2, "x", 0.2), list(3L, 3, "y", 0.3)),
  c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

result_schema <- structType(
  structField("key_a", "integer"),
  structField("key_c", "string"),
  structField("mean_b", "double"))

result <- gapply(
  df,
  c("a", "c"),
  function(key, x) {
    y <- data.frame(key, mean(x$b), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    colnames(y) <- c("key_a", "key_c", "mean_b")
    y
  },
  result_schema)
```

Note that I slightly changed the values of `df` because you had numbers as strings. Also, the `gapply` is used instead which returns a Spark Dataframe like `df`. It also requires an schema of the resulting df. In summary:

`df`:

```
  a b c   d
1 1 1 x 0.1
2 1 2 x 0.2
3 3 3 y 0.3
```

`result`:

```
  key_a key_c mean_b
1     1     x    1.5
2     3     y    3.0
```

Now you can do the join of both Spark Dataframes:

```
df2 <- join(df, result, (df$a == result$key_a) & (df$c == result$key_c), "left")
collect(drop(df2, c("key_a", "key_c")))
```

The extra columns can be remove with `drop` and data returned to the driver with `collect`:

```
  a b c   d mean_b
1 1 1 x 0.1    1.5
2 1 2 x 0.2    1.5
3 3 3 y 0.3    3.0
```